# How to show Material ui autocomplete multiple selected values in material ui chip using redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am currenly using redux form with material ui. I am trying to display selected autocomplete values in material ui chip and aslo I can delete chip values. Can someone suggest me How to implement this using redux form ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`redux-form-material-ui`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui)? It should correctly bind all the event listeners for you.

Comment: I don't think `redux-form--material-ui` actually has a tags/chip input solution. It would really be helpful